# Caliburn Micro get service instance

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn Micro for WinRT apps. I have registered a service in my App.xaml.cs see sample code below

```
public sealed partial class App
    {
        private WinRTContainer _container;

      public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Resuming += AppResuming;
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            _container = new WinRTContainer();

            _container.RegisterWinRTServices();

            _container.Singleton<ISampleService, SampleService>();
            //some more viewmodels & services added
        }

protected override void PrepareViewFirst(Frame rootFrame)
        {
            _container.RegisterNavigationService(rootFrame);
        }

protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
        {
            return _container.GetInstance(service, key);
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
        {
            return _container.GetAllInstances(service);
        }

        protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
        {
            _container.BuildUp(instance);
        }
}
```

Now, I have a utility class in which I want to get the instance of this `SampleService`.

How can I get the instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm supposing you are using MEF with Caliburn.Micro

So you can get an instance this way :

```
SampleService service = IoC.Get<ISampleService>();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I'm not using MEF. I tried the above code, but it returns null

Comment: Could you edit your answer and post your `App.xaml.cs` file ?

Comment: On your `SampleService` class do you have the `Export attribute` ? Something like `[Export(typeof(ISampleService))]`

Comment: No, do I need to put one?

Comment: It is normally used by MEF but since you mention that you don't use MEF, I'm not sure it will be useful but you can try it. By the way, which IoC are you using if not MEF ?

Comment: Sorry, I re-checked the code. I was passing the class name instead of interface.  e.g. `SampleService service = IoC.Get<SampleService>();` after correcting it to `SampleService service = IoC.Get<ISampleService>();` it worked, my bad :(, but thanks for following up.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Guerudo works, but you should never use `IoC.Get<>` unless you absolutely have to. Using a service locator is considered an anti-pattern.

The right when do get an instance is to use constructor injection. Say you have a MainViewModel, the do this

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    private readonly ISampleService _sampleService;

    public MainViewModel(ISampleService sampleService)
    {
        _sampleService = sampleService   
    }

}
```

And use _sampleService anywhere in your ViewModel.

And there is no need for any MEF attributes with Caliburn.Micro.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you should avoid pulling things from the container directly. Instead, consider using dependency injection.

For example, if you want to use `ISampleService` in `SomeUtility` class, which is called from `SomeViewModel`, then first you will need to register all three types in the container.

```
public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        ...

        _container.Singleton<ISampleService, SampleService>();
        _container.Singleton<SomeUtility>();
        _container.PerRequest<SomeViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Now, since `SomeUtility` depends on `ISampleService`, you should create `SomeUtility` constructor, which will accept `ISampleService`.

```
class SomeUtility
{
    private ISampleService _service;

    public SomeUtility(ISampleService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
}
```

And if `SomeViewModel` will be using `SomeUtility`, then appropriate constructor should be added to `SomeViewModel` as well.

```
class SomeViewModel : Caliburn.Micro.Screen
{
    private SomeUtility _utility;

    public SomeViewModel(SomeUtility utility)
    {
        _utility = utility;
    }
}
```

Finally, let's add `SomeViewModel` into `ShellViewModel` constructor.

```
class ShellViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IShell
{
    private SomeViewModel _vm;

    public ShellViewModel(SomeViewModel vm)
    {
        _vm = vm;
    }
}
```

That's it! `ShellViewModel` will get `SomeViewModel` instance, `SomeViewModel` will get `SomeUtility` and `SomeUtility` will have your `ISampleService`. And all this will be resolved by Container, so you don't need to create manually `new SomeUtility();` or pull from the container `IoC.Get<ISampleService>();`.

Also you might be wondering: What if `SomeViewModel` should be created on request, for example, when user click "Add" button? Well, I glad you asked. :) For that case you can use a factory method!

Just register it with the container.

```
public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        ...

        _container.Handler<IScreen>((x) => x.GetInstance<SomeViewModel>());
    }
}
```

Now you can easily inject it into constructor and use it to create as many instances of `SomeViewModel` as needed.

```
class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.AllActive, IShell
{
    private Func<SomeViewModel> _vmFactory;

    public ShellViewModel(Func<SomeViewModel> vmFactory)
    {
        _vmFactory = vmFactory;
    }

    public void Add()
    {
        var newVM = _vmFactory();
        ActivateItem(newVM);
    }
}
```